# SAR Instruction

Tags: assembly

```
sar eax, 6
...
sar eax, 0x1f
```

This arithmetic shift operation confuses me. Understand that it's taking the value of `eax` in hex then shifting it to the right by `6` and the same for the next operation by `0x1f`. See what the end result is, but still looking to better understand what's happening with these Shift Operations.
Say eax was `0x3338e3e0`, how exactly does it get to `0x00cce38f` step by step?

Comment: Next question you should ask is what's the difference between SHR and SAR :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to see what's going on if you work in binary.

`0x3338e3e0 is 0b00110011001110001110001111100000`

Shifting this right by 6 bits (i.e. removing the last 6 bits and adding 6 zeros at the start) gives -

`0b00000000110011001110001110001111`

Finally, turning this back into hex gives the value in your question.

`0b 0000 0000 1100 1100 1110 0011 1000 1111 = 0x00CCE38F`

Comment: I think you did a shr not a sar. Am I wrong? shr fill with zeros and sar fill with the sign bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\>python -c "print \"{0:8X}={0:b}\n{1:8X}={1:b}\".format(0x3338e3e0,0x3338e3e0>>6)"
3338E3E0=110011001110001110001111100000
  CCE38F=110011001110001110001111
```